# Unable to download and open files in Ionic and Angular

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, filesystems

I am currently developing an Ionic mobile app and I am attempting to download a file to the Documents directory on my cellphone, I am doing remote debugging. I have a MsSQL server and a ASP.NET 6 Web API. I have a download endpoint in the API and a document service in my Ionic frontend that makes an HTTP get request to the backend. However I am unable to download any documents, how can I download and view a file that I downloaded.

I am using the Ionic capacitor plugin Filesystem to write the file to the specified directory, but I cannot see the file in the directory. The following is a snippet of my typescript code.
For the file opener I am using the following import

```
import { FileOpener } from '@capawesome-team/capacitor-file-opener';
```

Here is a link to its documentation: [text](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-plugins/tree/main/packages/file-opener#openfileoptions)

```
async downloadDocument(document: Document){
    // Send the request and observe the full response to access headers
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.documentService.downloadDocument(document.documentId).subscribe(async (result: Blob) => {
     //Set file path
    const path = document.name + document.extension;
    console.log(path);
    //convert blob result to base 64
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(result);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      console.log(base64data);
    }

    const base64 = await this.convertBlobToBase64(result) as string;
    //Save file to device with error handling
    try {
    Filesystem.writeFile({
      path,
      data: base64 ,
      directory: Directory.Documents,
    }).then((writeFileResult) => {
      console.log('File Written');
      Filesystem.getUri({
          directory: Directory.Documents,
          path,
      }).then((getUriResult) => {
          console.log(getUriResult);
          const path = getUriResult.uri;
          FileOpener.openFile({path: path})
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(error => console.log('Error openening file', error));
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
    });
    console.log('writeFile complete');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to write file', error);
  }
   });
  });
  }
  
  convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log('convBase64', reader.result);
        resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

Here is the output of the console logs
[image: Console log output]